# identifier 'n' is undefined

Tags: c++

This is my **code**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int array[100], beg, mid, end, i, num;

cout << "Enter the value of an array" << endl;
cin >> n;

cout << "Enter the values in sorted order (asc or desc)" << endl;

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    cin >> array[i];

}

beg = 0;
end = n - 1;
cout << "Enter the value to searched in an array" << endl;
cin >> num;

while (beg <= end)
{
    mid = (beg + end) / 2;
    if (array[mid] == num)
    {
        cout << "Item found at this position" << (mid + 1);
        exit(0);
    }
    else if (num > array[mid])
    {
        beg = mid + 1;

    }
    else if (num < array[mid])
        end = mid - 1;
}
cout << "Number not found." << endl;

 return 0;
}
```

I am not able to find that what is my **error**. 
It is always displaying

> identifier 'n' is undefined
>   'n': undeclared identifier

Please any one give the suggestion to me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: declare n. like int n. before cin >> n;

Comment: Don't you think you need to actually declare 'n' as an int just like you did for `beg, mid, end, i, num`? I mean the error is pretty conclusive.

Comment: Declare n as int

Comment: @Abi next time block the code and click the `{}` editor button. this is only marginally better than the original and makes it too annoying for me to bother fixing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the beginning you must declare the variable :

```
int array[100], beg, mid, end, i, num, n;
```

**N** is the only variable that you don't declare but use.

Answer (score 0):

The  Error raise because You use the variable **n** before declaration. So First declare the variable `n` like other `mid,num,i` etc

Change Your Declaration line as follows

```
int array[100], beg, mid, end, i, num ,n; // declare n here before using

cout << "Enter the value of an array" << endl;
cin >> n;
```

Answer (score 0):

declare `n` as an `int` and you are good to go (for this bug only):

```
int array[100], beg, mid, end, i, num, n;
```